# Why can't I use string functions like scanf() or gets() strcat() strcpy() with character pointer variables?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I don't see why I keep getting a segmentation fault when I try to use ANY string function with a character pointer variable. I am fully aware that fgets() is better to ensure no overwriting occurs but I am just trying to write a program to demonstrate how string functions actually overwrite data in memory addresses whereas re-declaring the pointer variable i.e pValues = "New Name"; will point to a completely different set of addresses (that contain your required characters).

I know fully well that string functions do seem to work with pointer constants i.e. when defined like this:

```
char values[ ] = "Name Here";
```

BUT WHY do they not work for pointer variables i.e when defined like this:

```
char *pValues[ ] = "Name Here";
```

this is the part that keeps failing...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>     // required for strcpy(), strcat(), strlen()

main()

{
    
    char *pName = "Peter Jones";
    
    printf("The string pName is \'%s\'\n\n", pName);
    
    // Now lets change it to a longer string with more litterals...
    
    pName = "Dragons Den is GREAT!";
    
    printf("\nThe string pName is %s\n", pName);
    
    puts("Please enter a new string for pName ");
    gets(pName);
    
    printf("pName is now %s\n", pName); // THIS PRODUCES SEGMENTATION FAULT
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

The book I am learning from has NO mention of dynamic memory or heap - which I haven't yet covered.

Comment: The pointer `pName` points to some place you cannot write to: to the string literals.

Comment: ideally you wouldn't use `gets` with anything because it is a fundamentally unsafe function which has been deprecated.

Comment: Just what do you think `char *pValues[ ]= "Name Here" ;` gives you?

Comment: After revisiting this question a few times today, I see your title doesn't exactly match the code in your question. The example code only shows a failure with `gets()` but doesn't use `strcat()`, `strcpy()`, or `scanf()`. Failure using one of these functions doesn't imply that all of them will fail in similar ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> BUT WHY do they not work for pointer variables i.e when defined like this:
>
> char *pValues[ ]= "Name Here" ;

Because `pValues` is **not** a character pointer. It is an **array** of character pointers. If instead you do this:

```
char *pValues = "Name Here" ;
```

most of the functions you want to use will work just fine. The one exception is any function that tries to write to any memory pointed to by this pointer:

```
    puts("Please enter a new string for pName ");
    gets(pName);
    
    printf("pName is now %s\n", pName); // THIS PRODUCES SEGMENTATION FAULT
```

This part fails because `gets()` writes to a pointer that is pointing to a protected part of memory. You initialized it with:

```
    char *pName = "Peter Jones";
```

so `pName` points to memory that holds a string literal. As you saw, attempting to write to this area of memory results in a segfault.

You will need to learn more about dynamic memory allocation and the heap in order to use `gets()` with a pointer.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant - I did indeed use that in the code and I still get the segmentation fault - Thank you so much for responding so fast though! Any other ideas?

Comment: @AdrianSalt If you don't see my edit explaining the segfault, reload the page.

Comment: I do not see char `*pValues[ ]= "Name Here" ;` in the OPs code? Where did you get it from?

Comment: @P__J__ It is in the text of the question above the code. I added an explanation addressing the seg fault in the actual code.

Comment: **`so pName points to memory that holds a static string`** no it references string literal which is something different than static string (whatever it means)

Comment: `gets` should be avoided at any cost

Comment: **`attempting to write to this area of memory results in a segfault`** it may but it does not have to.

Comment: @P__J__ Updated to be more accurate. And agreed that the OP should avoid `gets()`. Still, the same issue would come up with `sprintf()` or `scanf()` or any other function that tries to write to a `char*` that is initialized in this way.

Comment: @P__J__ " it may but it does not have to." And it actually does in the case of the OP's compiler and system.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help on this matter, this is EXACTLY what I needed to know. I will continue my study of Heap and dynamic memory. Thank you for explaining that a variable pointer points to static memory. My only question on that would be, why does the following work if you can't overwrite using string functions - pName = "New Name"; This DOES work despite pointing to static memory...

Comment: @AdrianSalt The differences is that assignment causes the pointer to point to a different memory address. Where as `gets()` attempts to write to the memory that the pointer is already pointing to.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for explaining this. This is a HUGE help!

Comment: Because `char *pValues[ ]= "Name Here" ;` is an array of pointers, not a character pointer?

Comment: @user13783520 Your question used `pName` which is just a pointer. The initialization you have with `pValues` is illegal because you can't initialize an array of pointers to a single string.

Comment: @ryyker Yes, that would fix the declaration but then requires additional syntax to corretly use it with the string functions later in the OPs example code.

Comment: @AdrianSalt - If this answers you questions (as it appears to judging from your comments here)  you can say thank you in a very idiomatic way by clicking the little hollow check mark just to the left side, toward the top of this answer thius indicating that this post is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

*"Why can't I use string functions like scanf() [etc.] with character pointer variables?"*

*You* ***can***, but only by following the rules:

- the `type` defining the variable must be matched with the correct form of `initializer`.
- string literal initializers to pointer variables create not editable variables
- string literal initializers to char arrays are editable but not resizable.

The code example posted violates each of these.

This for example:

```
char values[] = "Name Here";
```

creates an *editable* [C string](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm) with the implicit length set to `sizeof("Name Here")`.  Because the size of the array is implicit (not specified), the initializer is required.  If however the array size is explicit, the initializer is optional.:

```
//either line is legal, and both resulting variables are editable
char values[20];
char values2[20] = "Name Here";
```

This:

```
char *pValues[]= "Name Here";
```

Is an array of pointers to `char`, which expects an initializer *list*, which can be accomplished by surrounding the [string literal(s)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) with `{...}`:

```
char *pValue[] = {"Name Here:"};
char *pValues[] = {{"Name Here:"},{"Address Here:"}};//see image
char *pValues2[] = {{"Name Here:"},{"Address Here:"}, ...};
```

resulting in from one to many *non-editable* C strings, each stored at a separate location in memory.

The expression:

```
char *pValue3 = "Name Here:";  //create non-editable variable
```

also places the contents of the string literal `"Name Here:"` into a memory location, and like the previous example, is in a *non-writable area of memory*.  Once it is initialized at creation, it is no longer editable.

For example, given:

```
char *var1 = "this is a non-editable string"; 
char var2[80] = {"This is an editable string"};

strcpy(var1, var2);//is illegal
strcpy(var2, var1);//is legal
```

The following image corresponds to `char *pValues[]` above:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`pName` is a pointer. You have assigned it it with the reference to the string literal. String literals cannot be modified - thus segfault which is one of the possible outcomes of the invoked UB.

You need to allocate some space for the string.

you can:

```
char str[100];
pName = str;
/* or */
pName = malloc(100);

/*or even*/
pName = (char[100]){};

/* then */

fgets(pName, 100, stdin);
```

do not use `gets` function as it is dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Adrian, I do not see why you "keep getting a segmentation fault when I try to use ANY string function with a character pointer variable" either... And I do not know how to judge scanf() over fgets() to ensure anything.

But back to this issue in particular, maybe I can help you. There some more things you also need to be "fully aware" of:

When you write

```
char *pName = "Peter Jones";
```

you are defining a string literal. `pName` will then point to an area in memory that has `"Peter Jones"` in the successive addresses following `pName`. Yes, `pName` is in some sense a pointer to char, but it is a pointer pointing to a constant area. You can make `pName` point to another address but can not use it to change the `"Peter Jones"` area thing. It is there to stay.

So when you write

```
// Now lets change it to a longer string with more literals...  
  
     pName = "Dragons Den is GREAT!";
```

It will succeed... But maybe it should not. When you do this you are saying Goodbye to the string `"Peter Jones"`. May be harmless but it is sort of a memory leak in the sense that it is there and it is lost.

But when you call *gets()* things are different: you are trying to write over a constant literal. You can not do that and you program is gone.

This has nothing to do with heap or stack or dynamic allocation. Just allocation. You need to have some writable area to point *gets()* to write to.

**Example**

```
char qName[40];
char* pName = "Peter Jones";
strcpy(qName, pName);
printf("The string pName is \'%s\'\n\n", pName);
// Now lets change it to a longer string with more litterals...
pName = "Dragons Den is GREAT!";
printf("\nThe string pName is %s\n", pName);
puts("Please enter a new string for qName ");
fgets(qName,10,stdin);
pName = qName;
// now pName points to the data read by gets()
printf("pName is now %s\n", pName);
```

Now it works. Declaring

```
char qName[40];
```

we have now 40 bytes available to use. `qName` is a pointer to an area of RAM of 40 contiguous bytes. In some sense it is a pointer to char.

But now you can tell *gets()* to read into `qName`. No problem here.
You can even point `pName` to `qName`. But then another area is lost: the area where `"Dragons Den is GREAT!"` is gone.

By the other hand, if you declare

```
char* p = NULL;
```

Now you have a pointer to char. It is now pointing to nothing, but at any time you can dynamically allocate memory and point `p` to that, ou make `p` point do an area of your program, like writing

```
p = qname + 2;
```

and then have `p` pointing to the third byte of `qName`.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for this, extremely helpful!  It seems once you assign a pointer variable like this pValue = "Name"; you cannot change it via a string function. But before assigning the pValue this way, fgets() does work, that's a little strange to me. It seems once assignment pValue = "name"; or char *pValue = "name"; a static thing occurs where you can only change it's values by pointing the pointer to a different location completely (whereas before assigning in this mannor i.e

char name[] = "Peter Jones";

char *pValues = &name[0];

then, fgets(pValues,81,stdin) does work.

Comment: It is important to note that initially `pName` points to a constant literal. You can make other pointers point to the same area, but as soon as the last one is changed to point to another place this area is lost for good. OTOH you can make `pName` points to another area, to never look back. Since `pName` was the only access to that area containing "Peter Jones" these bytes are lost. As for `gets()`, these functions does not allocate memory so you must pass a address the function can write to. In the example, `qName` points to a solid block of 40 char so it works